# Active directory sync and Organization Unit SP Online

Tags: sharepoint-online, search-results, active-directory, people-picker, synchronization

I'm synchronizing SharePoint Online with my Active Directory to get people information.

Now i have to difference those users by Organization Unit. The field orgNames is empty and it can't be used.

I have found what i need contained on SPS-DistinguishedName. Now the problem is, that SPS-DistinguishedName is not included in the Search Schema. I'm checking the Index option to manage it, but it isn't indexing.

¿Why? ¿It's impossible to manage that property? I have already waited 3 or 4 days to a possible synchronization internal job but with no success.

Thanks for the interest and help.

Comment: So is the issue that the SPS-DN property isn't populated, or that you cannot index the property in the search schema?

Comment: The issue was that the SPS-DN wasn't indexing. Days later it appeared. Thanks for your interest!

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to use OU for security reasons, the only way I can think of to do it effectively and consistently would be to create a claims augmentation solution.  On login, you can access the user's profile, then assign the OU as the claim.  You just have to remember to also implement the FillSearch and FillResolve components.

Claims Walkthrough: Writing Claims Providers for SharePoint 2010

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff699494.aspx

Comment: The question pertains to SPO. This isn't an option.

Comment: and if Trevor Seward read this, and didn't have an answer of his own, I'm going to go out on a limb and say there isn't one.  Dude's famous.  I'm just a dude.